# Flutter TabBar-like Indicator

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I need help identifying a Flutter widget that could do things as demonstrated by this GIF:
[image: Flutter TabBar-like Indicator]

I am interested in the circular indicator that allows me to browse through the resort locations like above. So far the closest thing that I have found was [TabBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html), but that isn't what I am exactly looking for. It seems far too complex to modify it to do the things that the GIF does, and I am very certain that there is a simpler solution, but after hours of exhaustive search through the list of widgets, I am not sure what to look for.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your UI, you can use [`dots_indicator`](https://pub.dev/packages/dots_indicator)    or better [`smooth_page_indicator`](https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_page_indicator)

```dart
class TestSnippet extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestSnippet({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestSnippet> createState() => _TestSnippetState();
}

class _TestSnippetState extends State<TestSnippet> {
  final PageController controller = PageController();

  int itemCount = 44;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: PageView.builder(
              itemCount: itemCount ~/ 3,
              controller: controller,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    index.toString(),
                  ),
                  Text("${index + 1}"),
                  Text("${index + 2}"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SmoothPageIndicator(
            count: itemCount ~/ 3,
            controller: controller,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It never occured to me that I could browse/use widgets developed by other developers.

Comment: Glad to help. I like the `SmoothPageIndicator`, if you like to create custom, you can use Container in Row with maintaining active index to have color effect.